# SQLAchemy store datetime with microsecond precision in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store a datetime as a timestamp in MySQL with microsecond precision: `2020-05-10 16:00:00.666666` using SQLAchemy

Here is my model:

```
class Order(Base):
  __tablename__ = "order"

  order_id = Column("id", String(50), primary_key=True)
  published_at = Column(
      "published_at", TIMESTAMP, nullable=True
  )
```

Here is my insert statement (done in a session):

```
order = Order(
            order_id=id,
            published_at=published_at,  #python datetime of format: 2020-05-10 15:00:00.555555+00:00
        )
session.add(order)
session.commit()
```

Using SQLLite i get what i expect. However when using MySQL i loose the fractional second part and get `2020-05-10 15:00:00`. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must specify the length for fractional part explicitly - i.e. the datatype must be `TIMESTAMP(6)`, not single `TIMESTAMP`. See the documentation for how it is performed in SQLAchemy.

Comment: I cannot find this referenced in the docs?

Comment: Needed the SQL specific dialect https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIMESTAMP had been imported like `from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP` however this does not give you access to the fsp parameter so you must use the sql specific dialect: `from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import TIMESTAMP`. Then you can use `TIMESTAMP(fsp=6)` in the model. Ref https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.TIMESTAMP